# PHP Notice: Undefined index

Tags: php, wordpress, notice

I am getting a Notice in a wordpress theme, but i think its a general PHP warning.

```
Notice: Undefined index: saved in ..\functions.php on line 255
```

The line 255 reads as:

```
if ( $_REQUEST['saved'] ) echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p><strong>'.$themename.' settings saved.</strong></p></div>';
```

Any suggestion, how i can fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change to:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['saved']))
```

You should consider using a method specific super-array like `$_GET` or `$_POST` instead of the more general `$_REQUEST` array.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( isset($_REQUEST['saved']) && $_REQUEST['saved'] ) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a general php notice. You should use ["empty"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function like this:

```
<?php

if (!empty($_REQUEST['saved']))
    echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p><strong>'
    . $themename
    . ' settings saved.</strong></p></div>';
```

This function will save you from "false", "0" and other "empty" values.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check if a variable is set using `isset()`. Not sure if this applies to your specific situation.

```
if ( isset($_REQUEST['saved']) ) {
     echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p><strong>'.$themename.' settings saved.</strong></p></div>';
}
```